# ngResource query, get and save

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

**I´m learning ngResource.**

I can "get" all the values of the json file. But I cannot do it work with one value (with query) and updating other.

**I get all with:**

```
this.total = userService.query();
```

**I´m trying to get one with:**

```
this.user = userService.query({"name":"Luis"});
```

**I´m trying to update with:**

```
var userToUpdate = userService.get({},{"name":"Luis"});
userToUpdate.name = "Name changed";
userToUpdate.$save();
```

**Now the general code**

**file1.html**

```
<div ng-app="module" ng-controller="controls as ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.total">
<span ng-bind="item.name"></span>
</div>

{{ ctrl.total }}

<br /><br />

{{ ctrl.user }}


</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-resource.js"></script>

<script>
var x = angular.module("module", ["ngResource"]);


x.factory("userService", ["$resource", function($resource)
{
return $resource("data.json");
}]);


x.controller("controls", ["userService", function(userService)
{

this.total = userService.query();

this.user = userService.query({"name":"Luis"});

var userToUpdate = userService.get({},{"name":"Luis"});
userToUpdate.name = "Name changed";
userToUpdate.$save();

}]);

</script>
```

**data.json**

```
[
{"id": 1, "name": "Mario", "lastname": "Perez"},
{"id": 2, "name": "Raul", "lastname": "Alvarez"},
{"id": 3, "name": "Pedro", "lastname": "Tomas"},
{"id": 4, "name": "Luis", "lastname": "Ranks"}
```

]

Anyone can help me? I´m a novice.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You miss understanding of what is json file

JSON is a format to store data. You can store **static** data in *.json files. So data in your data.json file is static and it is just static storage of some data.

So, when you do `userService.get()` with any query-parameters, you will get same response each time. You just getting static data. This data will be returned despite of query parameters

And again. *.json is just static data storage. You can not update it with `userService.$save()` method. You will get same static data as response.

To update something you need some *service* which will update your data. For example, you have some back-end, which is updating data.json.

So, normal case will be:

1. You have backend which handle requests of your frontend
2. Frontend will make some requests like GET /data or PUT /data/$id (to update data) or POST /data (to add data).
3. Backend will implement this methods

Code of front end should be:

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);
module.factory('userService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/data/:id');
}]);
module.controller('myCtrl', ['$http', function ($http) {
  userService.get(); // GET /api/data request will be performed
  userService.put({id: 1}); // PUT /api/data/1 request will be performed
  userService.post({name: 'someName'}); // POST /api/data will be performed
}]);
```

I wouldn't provide backend code. It will manipulate *.json file in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes! But WHY I can´t GET with the query JUST one "record", like: this.user = userService.query({"name":"Luis"});

Comment: Because it is static json file. You can get JUST ONE record in handler of data.json request. `data.json` is not script, that can handle query `name=Luis`. All file will be returned.